# Shopify API - Orders & external payments

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I am developing an e-commerce mobile application that interacts with multiple e-commerce platforms, such as Shopify.
My solution accepts payments and multi-merchant shopping baskets (potentially from different e-commerce platforms).  Therefore, my users need to pay through my system.

I have created a 'Shopify Application',  and we assume that the Merchant has installed it and I have the access-token to interact with the Merchant 'shop'.

My question is: "Using the API, how do I create the 'Shopify' orders and pay Shopify to make sure the order is accepted (at Shopify level) so that Shopify takes its fees, the merchant gets paid by Shopify, and Shopify charges me for that order?"

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should create for yourself a Sales Channel in Shopify. The merchant installs your App. They can then tick off what products from their Shopify store to sell on your marketplace. When a sale occurs on your marketplace, you can then inform Shopify of the order, and the merchant can deal with it correctly. Look into this, as it is essentially your only choice for working nicely with Shopify as a third party.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.  That's exactly what I intend to do.
Now in order to "correctly" handle the order (in an acceptable way for Shopify), my idea was to create a "Draft Order" and "complete" it.  As I could not obtain any confirmation from Shopify, would this way of proceeding be acceptable for them?

Comment: I do that all the time.